# Read text file and store the info into variable

Tags: shell, text-processing, ksh

I have a text file in which the records are in any one of the formats below:

SCI.txt

```
12-12-1990
12-12-1991
CSE Department
```

Or

```
12-12-1990,12-12-1991,CSE Department
```

I want them to be stored in 3 variables

```
a,b,c
```

I am looking for reading a txt file and storing the values into variable using shell script (ksh).

--- Update ---

I have nearly tried all the methods which are available over the internet. I couldnt able to get them worked.

Right now I am trying this method.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#reading the file content and storing in variable
_input="sci.txt"
while IFS='|' read -r fdate rdate dcname
do
   echo "$fdate $rdate $dcname"
done < "$_input"
```

sci.txt content as follows

```
demo1|demo2|demo3
```

But I am not getting any output for the above method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `sci.txt` doesn't end in a new line character. As explained in `man ksh`, the `read` builtin reads up to the first newline character by default:

```
  read [ -ACSprsv ] [ -d delim] [ -n n] [ [ -N n] [ [ -t  timeout]  [  -u
   unit] [ vname?prompt ] [ vname ... ]
          The  shell  input  mechanism.  One line is read and is broken up
          into fields using the characters  in  IFS  as  separators.   The
          escape  character,  \, is used to remove any special meaning for
          the next character and for line  continuation.   The  -d  option
          causes  the  read  to  continue  to the first character of delim
          rather than new-line.
```

So, unless you use `-d`, it will be looking for a newline character. If your file doesn't have one, it will not actually read anything. To illustrate:

```
$ printf 'demo1|demo2|demo3\n' > sci.newline
$ printf 'demo1|demo2|demo3' > sci.nonewline

$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for file in sci.newline sci.nonewline; do
    echo "Running on: $file"
    while IFS='|' read -r fdate rdate dcname
    do
        echo "$fdate $rdate $dcname"
    done < "$file"
done
```

Running this script returns the expected output on `sci.newline` but nothing for `sci.nonewline`:

```
$ foo.sh < sci.nonewline 
Running on: sci.newline
demo1 demo2 demo3
Running on: sci.nonewline
```

So, if your file ends with a newline (`\n`), everything should work as expected.

---

Now, the reason your `echo` statement works outside the loop is because the loop is never even run. When `read` doesn't encounter a `\n` character, it returns a non-0 (failure) exit status. The `while SOMETHING; do` construct will run only as long as `SOMETHING` is successful. Because `read` fails, the loop is never run and the `echo` inside the loop isn't executed. Instead, the script will run the `read` command and assign the variables and then, since the `read` returns failure, it will move on to the next part. That's why the next `echo`, the one outside the loop works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I got the desired answer. But whats the difference between these "echo "a:$a b:$b c:$c"" and "echo "$a $b $c""

Comment: @SiddharthRamakrishnan nothing, really. Just that `echo "b:$b"` will print an extra `b:` that helps you identify which variable is being printed. So, if `$b` is `foo`, `echo "b:$b"` will print `b:foo` while `echo "$b"` will only print `foo`.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the code in the OP's question doesn't work though. It works for me provided `demo1|demo2|demo3` is terminated by a newline character.

Comment: But what i have found is echo statement inside the do statement isn't helpful in printing anything. Because I used it and it doesnt print anything. And also it can't be removed because i am getting error. But I can confirm that variables are getting stored. And am able to print that out only if i use the echo outside of the loop. I still don't know whats the usage of echo insde the loop when it is printing nothing. 
#reading the file content and storing in variable
while IFS='|' read -r a b c
do
echo "$a $b $c"
done < "$file"
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas since I'm sure you know, could you explain why the `echo $vars` will work outside the loop? I assume it has something to do with `read` seeing the `eof` but I don't understand the mechanics well enough to explain it.

Comment: @SiddharthRamakrishnan `echo` could print nothing if `$fdate` starts with `\c`. Generally, you want to use `printf '%s\n' "..."` instead of `echo` for arbitrary data. Here, the fact that it works outside of the loop suggests the line is not terminated (`read` returns a non-zero exit status because it can't read a complete line, so you don't enter the loop). Best would be to fix your input so it contains a full line of text. If not use `while IFS='|' read -r a b c || [ -n "$a$b$c" ]` though that could still fail if the unterminated line contains just `||`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas but if the loop is skipped, why are the variables set outside it?

Comment: @terdon, in `printf foo | read a`, `read` does set `$a` to foo but exits with a non-zero exit status. Try `a=bar; printf foo | { read a; echo "$?: $a"; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=" ," read a b c; do
    echo a: $a b: $b c: $c
done < SCI.txt
```

Comment: This worked. I am so stupid and thought echo is not printing anything.